# Space on the top of a simple site

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I tried a simple hello world example from http://www.sencha.com/learn/hello-world/ and run it in the browser. Looks fine... But on two Android devices I get some space in the top of the site so that the first line will not be display... What happend?

There must be three Hello Worlds... But the first one ist lost behind the titlebar.. I checked it the a simple button and the same effect, the button will displayed as half.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Hello World</title> 

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="st2/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
    <link id="0" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="st2/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        Ext.application({
            launch: function () {
                Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                    fullscreen: true,
                    html: 'Hello World!<br/>Hello WOrld2<br/>Hello WOrld 3'
                });
            }
        });

    </script> 

</head> 
<body></body>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the theme from the application tag on the android manifest and it works now. Seems to be an android issues..

```
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/icon"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" <!-- Removed this line -->

    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some browser has problem displaying fullscreen pages. Try adding this:

```
viewport: {
    autoMaximize: true
}
```

to your Ext.Application object before the launch method. But read carefully the Sencha warning about this setting at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-cfg-autoMaximize

Comment: Thanks for reply but the additional css for viewport not helping. I can't understand why this happens on two android devices (4.3 and 2.3.6) and nobody has the same failure. This is the hello world example from sencha... So if an error exists anybody must fix it in the past